# Awk filter csv by string start value

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I want to filter out lines that START with word "CN" in the 2rd column from a file CSV and create a new CSV file with only that records.

Here is an example of my csv file

```
1;CN02BL00100000948999;;;
2;R30011781FUL1A60131PLCN1G34CN800166C0S00009C6UCB;;;
3;CN02BL00100000948569;;;
4;R 30011781FUL1A60131PLFG1G3BCC800625C0S00009C6UCB;;;
```

I'm using awk with this sintax

```
awk -F ";", '$1 ~ /CN/' $file > $TEMP/$file
```

But in this way my new file has row 1,2,3 and what i want is only row 1,3

I tryed to use ^ to filter from the start of the string in this way

```
awk -F ";", '$1 ~ /^CN/' $file > $TEMP/$file
```

but output file is null. What is wrong? Which is correct syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F ";" '$2 ~ /^CN/' $file > $TEMP/$file
```

No need for `,` . and also you need to match for `$2` not `$1`

Comment: Thank you it works! i know that was something stupid, and was not sure about $1 $2 (tried both) but real problem was comma...